# Windows Authentication for MS Access 2007 and MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, windows-authentication

I want to apply Windows Authentication on my MS Access database 2007 and 2010.
Firstly i want to know if this is possible? If yes then please provide me step by step instruction of setting it up.
If its not possible then provide me reason why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does not have built-in Windows Authentication. If you want to Windows Authentication, consider using MS SQL Server instead.

Reference: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-use-windows-authentication-my-ms-access-db-t1670092.html